# How to determine trend in series?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | Combined | Series |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.5 | 5 | 10 | Nan | 0.5, 5, 10 | **Increaseing** |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 1, 2, 3, 4 | **Increasing** |
| 8 | 5 | 3 | -1 | 8, 5, 3, -1 | **Decreasing** |
| 4 | 8 | 5 | 3 | 4, 8, 5, 3 | **neither** |

I have a table with the above column [1,2,3,4,Combined]

How can i try to automate the series determination of the combined column in python?

> ```
> def test(combine):
>     return "Increasing." if all(combine[i] < combine[i + 1] for i in range(len(combine) - 1)) 
> else 
>         "Decreasing." if all(combine[i + 1] < combine[i] for i in range(len(combine) - 1)) 
> else 
>         "neither!"
> ```

But this give me error with outcome '0'

Comment: What's the error message?  And what's `Combined` in the list.

Comment: @WingedSeal, its a key error "KeyError: 0'

Combined is hust a column that i created combining the column 1,2,3,4

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, it's working absolutely fine. Unless you pass something else beside list of int into test function.

Answer (score 0):

Your function works fine, *provided that*:

1. It is written with proper indentations (and line-continuations),
2. The column `Combined` contains lists of numbers (not e.g. strings such as `'[0.5, 5, 10]'`, or lists of strings, etc).

First, let's make sure the column contains lists of floats and/or ints:

```py
assert df['Combined'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, list) and all(isinstance(xi, (int, float)) for xi in x)).all()
```

If that is not the case, then correct it:

```py
from pandas.api.types import is_numeric_dtype

# test that the 4 first columns are numeric
assert df.iloc[:, :4].apply(is_numeric_dtype).all()
df['Combined'] = df.iloc[:, :4].apply(lambda s: s.dropna().tolist(), axis=1)
```

Then, make sure the syntax of your function is correct (indentation and line-continuation):

```py
def test(combine):
    return "Increasing." if all(combine[i] < combine[i + 1] for i in range(len(combine) - 1)) \
        else "Decreasing." if all(combine[i + 1] < combine[i] for i in range(len(combine) - 1)) \
        else "neither!"
```

Then:

```py
>>> df['Combined'].apply(test)
0    Increasing.
1    Increasing.
2    Decreasing.
3       neither!
```

You could make the function a bit more concise:

```py
def test(x):
    return "Increasing." if all(a < b for a, b in zip(x, x[1:])) \
        else "Decreasing." if all(a > b for a, b in zip(x, x[1:])) \
        else "neither!"
```

Or you could use Pandas Series built-in `monotonic` properties:

```py
def trend_comment(a):
    s = pd.Series(a)
    return 'increasing' if s.is_monotonic_increasing \
        else 'decreasing' if s.is_monotonic_decreasing \
        else 'neither'

>>> df['Combined'].apply(trend_comment)
0    increasing
1    increasing
2    decreasing
3       neither
```

(Note that the definition is slightly different than your tests: Pandas' [`is_monotonic_increasing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.is_monotonic_increasing.html) really means "monotonic non-decreasing", in which consecutive values are *either equal or* increasing).